# Understanding Onion Architeture

Tags: c#, design-patterns, onion-architecture

I am trying to grasp the important concepts of Onion Architecture and had a question I was asking myself after reading an article. Look at the Domain in the architecture showed in this image: http://tonysneed.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/onion-proj.jpg?w=282&h=494

What is the practicality of separating the Domain.Entities and Domain.Interfaces in two separate projects instead of having one Domain project with a entities and Interfaces folder? I am not very experienced but I don't see a scenario where one would thank god he has the domain entities and the domain interfaces separated..

Comment: This question belongs to another Programmers stack Exchange (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about so that the interface definitions can be published to clients, as open-source, while the implementation remains proprietary. Just for one of many reasons why this is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Three very good reasons which are already covered in [the article from which you got the image link](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/10/08/peeling-back-the-onion-architecture/):

1. **Testability**.  Unit test data context operations within that context.
2. **Maintainability**.  Maintain business logic without affecting data access logic and vis-a-versa.
3. **Longevity**.  ORM technologies improve or die (ala Linq-to-SQL), you are free to swap out your entire datacontext for a new one without wreaking havoc on your business logic.